# Two or more image on the same horizontally line even with resizing the page

Tags: html, css

I want my image to be horizontally aligned on the same line  no matter what the view port of the user is my html is :

```
  <div id="image_slider">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="img/1.jpg" id="1"/></li>
      <li><img src="img/2.jpg" id="2"/></li>
      <li><img src="img/3.jpg" id="3"/></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I was trying to to align them so in **first try:**

```
img{
  width:1200px;
  float:left;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

#image_slider ul,#image_slider li ,#image_slider,#container{
  display:block;
}
```

And in the **other try:**

```
#image_slider ul,#image_slider li ,#image_slider,#container{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

I changed to inline block but image still not as intended when resizing browser to smaller view port

Here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnnLzcyy/)

Comment: Use % for width so that it will shrink with window. and [fiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/) help everyone help you.

Comment: Do your images have to be 1200px in width or can they scale? I'm assuming they should scale since you mentioned resizing the page bu t your markup suggests otherwise.

Comment: @sareed I was trying to make a javascript slider so i want every image horizontally aligned then set the overflow to hidden

Comment: @Abdou Ok that makes sense. In that case you can use a placeholder div and use [positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) to keep it where you want. With the proper classes and js it should work for a slider.

Comment: lol ok, it's been a long day I think I misunderstood again. Sounds like the answers are the way to go :) You may have to use @media queries to control your responsiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block`, but also add `white-space:nowrap`:

```
#image_slider ul, #image_slider li, #image_slider, #container {
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vpcdnvh7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this... and for horizontal use display:inline, block is vertical.. inline-block is for both.  Also remove the set img width and let the parent container handle it.

```
 li {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#image_slider {
   width:1200px; /*set width slider*/
}
#image_slider ul {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}
#image_slider ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  width: 25%;
}
#image_slider ul li img {
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this css

```
#image_slider ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

**or**

> try this css

```
#image_slider ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```